# No Sniff activated with phantomjs scraping; workaround?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, sniffing

I am trying to access the match history site for a match on matchhistory.na.leaugeoflegends.com using Phantomjs. I was able to run the program successfully when I first wrote it but now I get a modified version of the page. The full version I first had included data from the site tables, which is what I am interested in. 
In the version I receive now I noticed this snippet at the top:

```
http-equiv="X-Content-Type-Options" content="nosniff
```

which I understand prevents repeated scraping of the site. Is there any way to work around this issue? For reference, I need data from about 200 matches from this site

The code I am using is:

```
import selenium.webdriver
driver = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH3/1002320097?gameHash=ce10e47aa8e2d965&tab=stats')
html=driver.page_source
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried using a chrome or firefox driver?

Comment: content=nosniff has no relation to scraping at all. Just go on with your scraping, what exactly stops you?

Comment: @SuperStew This ultimately solved the problem (using Firefox). It seems like the site won't accept headless browsers

Comment: @Vaviloff Using Phantomjs would only occasional return the correct site data. Often it would return much less than I knew was on the page. Thanks!